# How to split a big mysqldump file for get each structure and data separately?

Tags: mysql, bash, csplit

Based on https://gist.github.com/jasny/1608062#file-mysql_splitdump-sh

```
#!/bin/bash

####
# Split MySQL dump SQL file into one file per table
# based on http://blog.tty.nl/2011/12/28/splitting-a-database-dump
####

if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
  echo "USAGE $0 DUMP_FILE [TABLE]"
  exit
fi

if [ $# -ge 2 ] ; then
  csplit -s -ftable $1 "/-- Table structure for table/" "%-- Table structure for table \`$2\`%" "/-- Table structure for table/" "%40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE%1"
else
  csplit -s -ftable $1 "/-- Table structure for table/" {*}
fi

[ $? -eq 0 ] || exit

mv table00 head

FILE=`ls -1 table* | tail -n 1`
if [ $# -ge 2 ] ; then
  mv $FILE foot
else
  csplit -b '%d' -s -f$FILE $FILE "/40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE/" {*}
  mv ${FILE}1 foot
fi

for FILE in `ls -1 table*`; do
  NAME=`head -n1 $FILE | cut -d$'\x60' -f2`
  cat head $FILE foot > "$NAME.sql"
done

rm head foot table*
```

I want to split my big mysqldump file for get each table structure and table data separately.

I'm no expert in bash script and I search the pattern for split the dump file to get several files like :

- table_one_structure.sql
- table_one_data.sql
- table_two_structure.sql
- table_two_data.sql
- etc ..

Comment: If you want to specify the file name as table_name then I think you need to write a shell script as per my exp, or else for every table it create the separate file but that will be dynamic file name

Comment: the script split the big mysqldump file to get table_one.sql, table_two.sql, etc .. Here I want split data and structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also split dump with awk script:
`cat dumpfile | gawk -f script.awk` (or `./script.awk < dumpfile` if you make it executable).
It will create pairs of `tablename.schema.sql`, `tablename.data.sql` files in current directory for each table in mysqldump in one pass.

Warning: there is no special handling for characters in table names - they are used *as is* in filenames.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    is_data=0; is_struct=0; is_header=1; is_footer=0; i=0; tname="UNKNOWN_TABLE";
}

/^($|-- |\/\*\!)/ && !/^-- Table struct/ {
  # accumulate header lines
    if (is_header && !is_struct) { header[i]= $0; i++; } 
}

/^-- Table structure for table/ {
    is_struct=1; is_header=0; i=0; is_data=0;
    tname=substr($6,2,length($6)-2);
    tables[tname]=1;
    print "--" > tname".schema.sql"
    for (i in header) print header[i] >> tname".schema.sql";
    ###print "STRUCT:", tname;
}

/^-- Dumping data for table/ {
    is_data=1; is_header=0; is_struct=0;
    tname=substr($6,2,length($6)-2);
    print "--" > tname".data.sql"
    for (i in header) print header[i] >> tname".data.sql";
    ###print "DATA_START for table ",tname;
    i=0
}

{ if (is_struct) { print $0 >> tname".schema.sql"} }
{ if (is_data) { print $0 >> tname".data.sql" } }

/^UNLOCK TABLES/ {
    is_data=0; is_struct=0;
    ###print "DATA_END for table ",$tname;
}

/^(--|\/\*.40[0-9]{3} SET .+\*\/;$)/ {
    if (!(is_header || is_struct || is_data)) {
        # accumulate footer lines
        is_footer=1;
        footer[$0]=1;
    }
}

END { 
    # append footer to files
    for (t in tables) {
        for (f in footer) {
            print f >> t".schema.sql";
            print f >> t".data.sql";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: without the `enter code hereenter code here` at line 48. Your script work perfectly. Thanks [Yuri Lachin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6219718/yuri-lachin) !

Comment: :-) Remains of comment string left. Sorry.

Comment: Split table structure not work for me. The script creates the filles with names but they are empty. Any recommendation? Thanks!!!